# short jQuery solution for a javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need a jQuery solution of a JavaScript code and more shorter than it is.

**Code**:

```
if (event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("class").include("newSearch"))
```

where `event` is coming from,

```
$(document).on('click', '#divCl > #lnkCl', function (event) {
```

JQuery version : 2.2.4

**HTML Code**:

```
<div class"newSearch">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="divCl">
                    <div id="lnkCl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not the exact code, as we have different use for the divs in between.

Comment: We have div with id as `lnkCl` as child of div with id `divCl` multiple times in same page.

Comment: ^ That is another issue then, as you're duplicating `id` attributes when the *must* be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: What We have unique is that grandparent of grandparent div is having class name as `NewSearch`, with only one occurrence in same page.

Comment: In any case we need to see the relevant HTML and also your attempt to write the jQuery to solve this. Remember that SO is here to debug code you've written, not write code for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#divCl > #lnkCl', function(event) {
  if ($(this).parents(".newSearch").length) {
    // do your thing
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks